# TextBlock disappears in windows phone emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7, expression-blend-4

I have textblock in my application, everything seems good, it is perfectly visible (all textblock) in expression blend and in visual studio. The problem is when I launch emulator. Textblock disappears at one moment, exactly after "Targets: Lower back, rectus and transversus abdominis, obliques, and butt" . Is it bug from emulator, or sth is wrong? I deleted some part of text.

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Excercises;component/Images/tlo.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="4610">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,214" Width="472" Name="TextBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" > 
            <LineBreak />
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="27" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" TextDecorations="Underline">
           7 Waist-Slimming Ab Exercises
            </Run>
            <LineBreak />
            <LineBreak />            
        <Run Text="Fly up"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="Target: Rectus abdominis"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="1.Sit on a folded towel on floor, lean back to rest on elbows and place feet together on a wall in front of you so that knees are bent about 90 degrees."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="2.Extend legs up, keeping feet against wall, then press rounded lower back into floor and squeeze abs as you lift arms to reach toward feet, elbows soft. Make it harder: Press feet into wall as you reach."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="3. Do 20 pulses: Curl torso up 1 inch, then lower 1 inch."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="4.Do 3 sets, hugging knees to chest to rest between sets."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="Pelvic Scoop"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="Targets: Lower back, rectus and transversus abdominis, obliques, and butt"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text=" 1.Lie faceup on floor with back resting on folded towel, knees bent and feet flat on floor, arms by sides."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="2.Cross right ankle onto left thigh just above knee so bent right knee points out to side; flex left foot so only heel rests on floor."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="3. Rounding lower back and squeezing abs, lift hips off floor so pelvis tilts up toward ribs. Curl pelvis as far as you can without arching back; pull abs in to lift rather than press through left heel. Lower to floor."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="4.Do 10 reps, holding the lift for 10 seconds on the final one. Switch sides and repeat. Do 3 sets."/>

    </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using real layout conventions (Grid, etc.) rather than one giant TextBlock? you'll only end up frustrated with the issue of controls exceeding 2000px not displaying. (If this isn't your issue right now, anyway)

Comment: So TextBlock cannot be bigger than 2000px, right? Well, I am newbie in this now, so i don't get idea of grids,canvas etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you are taking right now for a large chunk of text is definitely something you want to reconsider. Even with all the extra formatting, you might want to stack the labels, or position them in the context of a Grid (like William mentioned).

Details here:

- [How to use a StackPanel](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-StackPanel-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx)
- [How to use a Grid](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Grid-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx)